# Lumen Validation allow only one Get Parameter

Tags: php, lumen

In my project I use Lumen and I want to implement some kind of validation for my GET request.

The example URL would look like this:

> [URL]/blubb/bla?tags[]=1&tags[]=2

In my code I validate the URL like this:

```
public function handleRequest(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $validatedData = $this->validate($request, [
            'tags' => 'nullable|array'
        ]);
    } catch (ValidationException $th) {
        // return Error.
    }
    
    // go on.
}
```

My problem is that if a user uses an URL like this one, the validation does not trigger and the "go on." part is called.

> [URL]/blubb/bla?invalidParameter=1

Is there a way to only allow a single "kind" of GET Parameter?

EDIT:
The "tags" is nullable because my API endpoint can be called without any GET parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the full array with `$request->all()` and have a look at the keys.

```
$paramValidation = $request->all()
unset $paramValidation['tags'];
if (count($paramValidation)) {
    // error
}
```

---

However, maybe you just want to ignore other params. Have a look at the method `$request->validated()`.